# Issue with talend aws s3 components(ts3get)

Tags: java, talend, awss3transfermanager

I am trying to download all files in my s3 bucket in one go.
  I am able to list all files using ts3list but not able to download all files .
  ts3get is only downloading the last file.
  Please guide me through this or this function is not applicable in talend.
Please go the below link , I am getting same issue.
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=45397

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a logical error.

If you use the same layout as in the link (I couldn't verify this since you didn't provide any information about your job layout), only the last entry will be used since you go to the file get component `onComponentOk` which will be triggered when all entries have been iterated through.

Instead, the get file component should be placed in the iterator.